# Why does wifi not work after elementary OS 5.0 Juno installs on my late 2008 MacBook Pro?

Tags: wifi, macbook, release-juno

elementary OS 5.0 Juno works perfect on my 15" inch late 2008 MacBook Pro when I run the OS on USB stick.  In particular, the [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi) works flawlessly.

So why does wifi **not work** after elementary OS 5.0 Juno is installed on the hard drive?  The wifi will not work and won't attempt to try and use it.  That makes no sense to me and is a pretty bad bug as I installed the OS based on favorable USB bootable stick experience.

Definitely need a new elementary OS to download as if my wifi doesn't work, I cannot download any bug fixes to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Just needed to install the drivers for the wifi adapter manually after the install; they somehow didn't get installed from the usb.
Just open a terminal window. Then command: `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did the wifi work when you bootet into Juno from the thumb drive? If so, did you install updates while the system was written to the HDD? Do you use any 3rd party software (bootloader or bootmanager)?

The problem with my late 2007 MBP is, that it boots and run well from the usb-stick, even wifi works perfectly. But the [installer crashes](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18289/elementary-os-5-0-won-t-install-on-macbook-pro-3-1-core2duo) while it writes the system to the HDD.

So far, I have no clue why.